# How can I create symmetric pyramid in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, static, void

So I'm kind of close to the answer
but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
public static void drawDiamond (int i1) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2*i1-1 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=Math.abs(i1-i); j>=1; j--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        int t = Math.abs(i-i1);
        for (; t <= (2*i1-1); t ++){
            if (t == (t*2-i1) && t !=0)
            break;
            System.out.print("*");
        }System.out.println();
     }

    }
```

And here is my expected answer and my answer[image]

Comment: So positioning is correct, you just don't get enough stars printed. Locate the condition that controls this and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: I suggest that you read ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Particularly the "rubber duck" technique.  (Apart from anything else, to be a programmer you need to learn how to debug your own code.  And the only real way to learn it is to do it for yourself.  It is like learning to play a musical instrument.)